# How to store 999 value in character data type

Tags: c

In one of the interview. A person asked I want to store 999 value in character data type. How to do it?

999 = 1111100111 (In binary representation)

character is of type 1 byte. 8bits.

```
int main()
{
    int a =999;
    signed char c = 999;
    printf("%d %d",a,c);
}
```

when I compile the program I get the warning as

```
storeintinchar.c:6:1: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

when I run it:

```
a=999. c=-25;
```

when I change `character` to `unsigned char c=999;`

when I compile the program I get the warning as

```
storeintinchar.c:6:1: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

when I run it.

`a=999. c=231;`

1. Can we store 999 value in character is it possible in any way to do that.
2. What was interviewer trying to test?
3. Is it possible to store 999 value in wchar_t. When I am searching for above question I found in  GNU C  Library wchar_t is always 32 bits wide. Then we can use it. Is it works

   ```
    int main()
    {
        int a =999;
        unsigned char c = 999;
        wchar_t d=999;
        printf("%d %d %d",a,c,d);
    }
   ```

output: 999 231 999

wchar_t is 4 bytes. I was able to store 999 value in it.

I am thankful for all the people part of stackoverflow providing quick results and  giving reasonable answers.

Comment: The short, and only, answer is: You can't. A `char` is generally one byte, 8 bits, and can't store values outside that range. But you can store it in *two* `char` variables, using bitwise operations.

Comment: Well actually you have answered you own question inside your question. And the interviewer probably wanted to test your basic computing skills.

Comment: You can't store 999 in a char, but you can in a wchar. Like Michael said, this was a test of general computing knowledge.

Comment: If the interviewer said "character data type" could he have meant 3 characters?  That is, converting to ASCII?  It is unclear what was really asked.

Comment: How about 0x39 (00111001)? It wouldn't work for 998, but it's fine for 999. *(Sorry, I couldn't resist...)*

Comment: You can only do that on some architectures that have CHAR_BIT >= 10

Comment: Do not take the job, if a potential employer asks stupid questions I decline their offer as they have shown their incompetence.

Comment: Maybe the interviewer wanted `char data[] = "999";`?

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically store 999 in one byte if the compiler has proper byte size. Check `limits.h` for size of your current `char` type. But of course you can't expect such size of `char`for every architecture and every compiler. Usually for modern architectures one char is 8 bits and you just can't store there such a big number without any additional memory used.

Answer (score 1):

You can store 999 (and also some other numbers), however you will need to implement an algorithm which sort of "compresses" the number, with the outcome that the bits of the char do not mean what they usually, but are holding a key to the solution ... the algorithm is like:

```
bit idx:      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
bit value:    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

So, for this to be 999 you do:

```
999 = bit[0] * 9 * (10 ^ 0) +    // 1 * 9 + 
      bit[1] * 9 * (10 ^ 1) +    // 1 * 90 + 
      bit[2] * 9 * (10 ^ 2) +    // 1 * 900
      bit[3] * 9 * (10 ^ 3) +    // 0 * 9000 ....
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. A `char` data type (on every platform you are likely to come across) has 8 bits, and thus can encode a maximum of 256 values. Assuming you need *all* the values up to 999, that's more than it can encode. As a `char` is signed, it stores values only between -128 and +127.

*However*, if you only need to encode *some* of the values up to and including 999, you could use a look up table.

Alternatively, you could use (e.g.) 2 `char` values, sandwiched together to make a 16 bit integer, which could store unsigned numbers up to 65535.

Comment: Yes lookup table is a possible solution, but I think he wants to store the value *in* the char, as stated in the question

Answer (score 0):

To store the value 999 in `char` data, you need to break it up and store it in 2 or more `char`s. For example (using 7 bits of each `char`):

```
char first = 999 % 128
char second = 999 / 128
```

Also note that it's possible for a `char` to *represent* any value. For example, you could say that the value 1 represents 999, and then only store 1. This is different to being able to *store* a value.